# openCV no abre la cámara

Tags: android, opencv

Este es el código con el que estoy trabajando en openCV. La idea es comparar la iamgen de la cámara con una de un archivo.

Este es el log del fallo:

> D/JavaCameraView: Preview Frame received. Frame size: 460800
>
> E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (s >= 0) in void
>   cv::setSize(cv::Mat&, int, const int*, const size_t*, bool), file
>   /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line
>   310
>
> E/org.opencv.core.Mat: Mat::n_1create__JIII() caught
>   cv::Exception:
>   /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:310:
>   error: (-215) s >= 0 in function void cv::setSize(cv::Mat&, int, const
>   int*, const size_t*, bool)
>
> W/dalvikvm: threadid=11: thread exiting
>   with uncaught exception (group=0x41ca8930)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1781
>
> CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception:
>   /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:310:
>   error: (-215) s >= 0 in function void cv::setSize(cv::Mat&, int, const
>   int*, const size_t*, bool)
>
> ```
>               ]
>                   at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_create(Native Method)
>                   at org.opencv.core.Mat.create(Mat.java:355)
>                   at midlaboratories.reconocimientoconcamara.MainActivity.onCameraFrame(MainActivity.java:192)
>                   at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:392)
>                   at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:373)
>                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
> ```
>
> D/JavaCameraView: Preview Frame received. Frame size: 460800
>
> D/JavaCameraView: Preview Frame received. Frame size: 460800
>   >
>   D/CameraBridge: call checkCurrentState
>                   call processExitState: 1 D/JavaCameraView: Disconnecting from
>
> Notify thread
>
> Waiting for thread I/Process: Sending signal.
>
> PID: 23475 SIG: 9 Application terminated.

Creo que puede ser la configuración de la cámara en tamaño o posición, estoy usando una tablet de 10" en apaisado.

Fichero Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
    /**
     * class name for debugging with logcat
     */
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    /**
     * the camera view
     */
    private CameraBridgeViewBase mOpenCvCameraView;
    /**
     * the template image to use
     */
    private static final int TEMPLATE_IMAGE = R.drawable.ajustes;
    /**
     * the result matrix
     */
    Mat result;
    /**
     * the camera image
     */
    Mat img;
    /**
     * the template image used for template matching
     * or for copying into the camera view
     */
    Mat templ;
    /**
     * the crop rectangle with the size of the template image
     */
    Rect rect;
    /**
     * selected area is the camera preview cut to the crop rectangle
     */
    Mat selectedArea;

    /**
     * frame size width
     */
    private static final int FRAME_SIZE_WIDTH = 1024;
    /**
     * frame size height
     */
    private static final int FRAME_SIZE_HEIGHT = 576;
    /**
     * whether or not to use a fixed frame size -> results usually in higher FPS
     * 640 x 480
     */
    private static final boolean FIXED_FRAME_SIZE = true;

    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

                    // load the specified image from file system in bgr color
                    Mat bgr = null;
                    try {
                        bgr = Utils.loadResource(getApplicationContext(), TEMPLATE_IMAGE, Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // convert the image to rgba
                    templ = new Mat();
                    Imgproc.cvtColor(bgr, templ, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);//Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2RGBA);

                    // Imgproc.Canny(templ, templ, 50.0, 200.0);

                    // init the crop rectangle, necessary for copying the image to the camera view
                    rect = new Rect(0, 0, templ.width(), templ.height());

                    // init the result matrix
                    result = new Mat();
                    img = new Mat();

                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                } break;
                default:
                {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                } break;
            }
        }
    };

    public MainActivity() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mOpenCvCameraView = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1_activity_java_surface_view);

        // Michael Troger
        if (FIXED_FRAME_SIZE) {
            mOpenCvCameraView.setMaxFrameSize(FRAME_SIZE_WIDTH, FRAME_SIZE_HEIGHT);
        }

        mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);

        mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, mLoaderCallback);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mOpenCvCameraView != null)
            mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {}

    public void onCameraViewStopped() {}


    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        img = inputFrame.gray();

        // copying the image into the camera preview
        // selectedArea = img.submat(rect);
        //  templ.copyTo(selectedArea);

        // template matching
        //Imgproc.Canny(img, img, 50.0, 200.0);

        /// Source image to display
        Mat img_display = new Mat();
        img.copyTo( img_display );

        /// Create the result matrix
        int result_cols =  img.cols() - templ.cols() + 1;
        int result_rows = img.rows() - templ.rows() + 1;
        result.create(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);

        /// Do the Matching and Normalize
        int match_method = Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF;
        Imgproc.matchTemplate(img, templ, result, match_method);

        Core.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

        Core.MinMaxLocResult minMaxLocResult = Core.minMaxLoc(result, new Mat());

        Point matchLoc = null;
        /// For SQDIFF and SQDIFF_NORMED, the best matches are lower values. For all the other methods, the higher the better
        if( match_method  == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF || match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED )
        {
            matchLoc = minMaxLocResult.minLoc;
        }
        else
        {
            matchLoc = minMaxLocResult.maxLoc;
        }

        /*Imgproc.rectangle(img_display, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(), matchLoc.y + templ.rows() ), new Scalar(255,0,0) );
        Imgproc.rectangle(result, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(), matchLoc.y + templ.rows()), new Scalar(255, 0, 0));

        return img_display;*/

        //Añadido de otro post float (2) e if(), también el result
        float thresholdMatchForMin = 0.02f;
        float thresholdMatchForMax = 0.08f;
        //                minMaxLoc.minVal < thresholdMatchForMin ||
        if (minMaxLocResult.maxVal > thresholdMatchForMax)
        {
            /// Show me what you got

        }


        return img_display;
    }
}
```

Me puede ayudar alguien? Gracias

Comment: Hola, estas pidiendo los permisos para abrir la camara?

Comment: @Carlosgub los tengo en el manifiest

Comment: Hola claro, pero si tu celular es android 6 o posterior tiene que pedir el perniso explicitamente. Aca te dejo la info https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting?hl=es-419